# How to export a file to a specific location using java code

Tags: java, file, export

I am making an installer program for a minecraft mod of mine and i want to make it that when you click a button it will take the .jar file from the selected file and then place it in the minecraft directory which is "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\mods" How would you do that?

Comment: If you want someone to write the code for you then you have come to the wrong place.  If you have some code that isn't working, please post it and explain the errors or problems you have.

Comment: Installers for mods? Which minecraft is this? My minecraft directories are also different.

Comment: Mark, what would be the right place to ask?

Comment: Have you tried [IzPack](http://izpack.org/)?

Comment: No i have not, i will try it out now.

Comment: Perhaps consider using:  Files.copy(Path from, Path to) . This is from the Files class which was introduced in Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

File.copy(Path from, Path to, options);